# Arduino-compatible wireless technology which can be suitable for transmitting data

Tags: wireless, remote-control

## Introduction

I've been meaning to build a vehicle using arduino components and LEGO. I have a mechanical clamp built with arduino which will be locked on top of a custom LEGO build (It should be made out of LEGO blocks and arduino sensors). In my mind, it resembles a crawler.

## Question

I've been looking for a way of controlling it remotely.
I only have experience with IR controllers but I'm not sure if this technology would fit for my project.

What I'm looking for is a technology wich could transmit data to an Arduino board (thus, an emitter and a receiver component) which, in my case, could comfortably handle a veichle.

Plus, it should have a range of action of at least 5 meters (15 ft).

If such technology exists, do you know any controller which could do the job for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use radio transmitter/receivers, they are typically called RF (Radio Frequency) modules.

Typical examples are nRF24L01+ (2.4 GHz), or RF 315/433 modules (on 315/433 MHz).

There are more possibilities, but these are the most used on Arduino and libraries are available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you happen to know where to find these modules?

Comment: You mean where to buy them? AliExpress, or if you want genuine products, try Mouser, Digikey

Answer (score 0):

Try a pair of Wixels (https://www.pololu.com/product/1336).  A pair of Wixels (one at the PC, one on the crawler) act as a fast USB cable emulator.  The PC-connected Wixel shows up as a USB port, and the one on the crawler (with a Wixel sheild) emulates the Arduiono end of a USB cable.  These are very easy to use, and in addition to remote control will allow you to wirelessly program the Arduino controller.

The ability to remotely program the crawler is a real god-send, as now you don't have to retrieve the crawler and connect it to a hardware USB cable for programming.

Just my $0.02

Frank